# how to compute the follow-position of a regular expression(R.E) from a parse tree

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction, logical-grouping

I was computing the follow position of a regular expression `R.E = (a|b)*abb`
by using these algorithms. From given algorithm by using second property i found a problem and can not get the answer. How can be the i is a position in lastposition(n)

1.If `n` is a `cat-node` with left child `C1` and right child `C2` then for every position `i` in `lastpos(C1)` , all positions in `firstpos(C2)` are in 
    `followpos(i)`.

2.If `n` is a star-node, and `i` is a position in `lastpos(n)` , then all positions in `firstpos(n)` are in `followpos(i)`.

The fistpostion and the lastposition at every node computed first.